# My snowsql connection locked when trying to connect and run config

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to set up a Snowpipe, and I have created my warehouse, database and table and am trying to stage the filew with snowsql.

```html
USE WAREHOUSE IoT;
USE DATABASE SNOWPIPE_TEST;

CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE my_stage;

CREATE OR REPLACE FILE_FORMAT r_json;

CREATE OR REPLACE PIPE snowpipe_pipe
   AUTO_INGEST = TRUE,
   COMMENT = 'add items IoT',
   VALIDATION_MODE = RETURN_ALL_ERRORS
  AS  (COPY INTO snowpipe_test.public.mytable
  from @snowpipe_db.public.my_stage
  FILE_FORMAT = (type = 'JSON');
  
  
CREATE PIPE mypipe AS COPY INTO mytable FROM @my_stage;
```

I think something is locked but I am not sure.

I tried to save the config file as config1 and made a copy. It hung, then I remove the copy and tried to connect and there was no error, it just hung

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you _want_ to use snowpipe, or just load some data? I'm asking because you're configuring an internal stage here. If you just want to load some files from an internal stage, use COPY, without snowpipe.

Comment: I do want to use Snowpipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the auto ingest parameter it's AUTO_INGEST rather than AUTO-INGEST, but note that this option is not available for an internal stage. So when you try to run this command using an internal stage it should error with a message pointing this out.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-pipe.html#optional-parameters

Also you don't need the bracket between the "AS" and "copy" on line 5.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I fixed the Auto_Ingest and the bracket, looks like it is not a feature yet, I will look at other stages, since I want to use snowpipe.